# Getting error "invalid operands of types `float' and `int' to binary `operator^'" C++

Tags: c++, function

Keep getting error "invalid operands of types `float' and`int' to binary `operator^' when compiling.  I believe it is an issue with the 4/3 but I'm unsure how to make it work.  I think I am just missing a simple part of code but have spent over an hour trying to figure it out

```
#include <iostream>
#define Pi 3.14159265359
using namespace std;



float SphereVol (float r)
{
      float vol;
      vol = ((4/3)*(Pi)*(r^3));
      return vol;
}

int main()
{

float r, f = SphereVol(r);

for (r=0; r=4; r+(.2))
{
cout.precision(7);
cout << "Radius: " << r << "  volume: " << SphereVol(r) << endl;     
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I've edited the code from above and now it is having problems displaying correctly and for some reason the `cout.precision(8)` is making the output come out with the decimal places incorrect.  It is supposed to list like 
`radius= 4.0000000 volume= .xxxxxxx`
but is leaving decimal off whole numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#define Pi 3.1415926
using namespace std;



float SphereVol (float r)
{
   float vol;
   vol = ((4.0/3.0)*(Pi)*(r*r*r));
   return vol;
}

int main()
{

float r;
float f = SphereVol(r);

for (r = 0; r <= 4; r += .2)
{
cout.precision(8);
cout << "Radius: " << r << "  volume: " << SphereVol(r) << endl;    
}

cout << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Decimals are now displaying 
Example: `radius= 3.20000005
          radius= 3.40000006`

It is supposed to display like

`Radius: 0.200000 volume: 0.033503
    Radius: 0.400000 volume: 0.268082
    Radius: 0.600000 volume: 0.904778
    Radius: 0.800000 volume: 2.14466
    Radius: 1.000000 volume: 4.18879`

Comment: instead of saying "output come out weird", post the output you got and explain how it differs from what you expected. Also the edit should really have been a new question since it is nothing to do with the original issue

Comment: If you want to see trailing zeroes then you have to use `cout << fixed;` also .  These flags are sticky so you can do them before the loop, instead of inside the loop.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this.  Thats why all of my stuff keeps getting down-voted I am not clear on how this works.

Comment: Can you check out the code for me ? I've been stuck on this for an hour.  The last 4 are showing up  `radius= x.0000001`

Comment: Yes, that's because floating-point is not exact. You can use `double` instead of `float` to get extra precision. Beyond that, there's nothing you can do about it except either display with less precision, or stop using floating point for `r`. [Read this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for further info.

Comment: Radius: 0.000000 volume: 0.00000
    Radius: 0.200000 volume: 0.0335103
Radius: 0.400000 volume: 0.268082
Radius: 0.600000 volume: 0.904778
Radius: 0.800000 volume: 2.14466
Radius: 1.000000 volume: 4.18879

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ (and also in C), the `^` operator is the bit-wise eXclusive OR (XOR) operator that only works on integer types.

It is not a power operator to raise a number to a power.

You could rewrite your function like:

```
float SphereVol (float r)
{
  return (float) (4.0 / 3.0 * Pi * r * r * r);
}
```

In your code, the expression (4/3) will be done with integer math, which discards any remainder and will evaluate to 1.  In my code above, I use 4.0 and 3.0 to force double precision floating point math to be done for the division and following multiplications.  I then cast that double precision result to a single precision float to match the function's return type.

For more generally raising a number to a power, there are the std::pow functions if you `#include <cmath>`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow

Make sure that `float` has enough precision for your math.  You may prefer to use `double` instead, which has more precision.

Also, your loop syntax is wrong.  The way you wrote it will cause an infinite loop.  Try this instead:

```
for (r = 0; r <= 4; r += 0.2)
```

Comment: The `4/3` in the question is integer division. In this answer, `(float) 4/3` is floating-point division; the `(float)` cast applies to the constant `4`, not to the expression `4/3`. Still, it would be clearer to write `4.0/3.0`. There's also a `pow` function, but it's overkill in this case.

Comment: Hey man I've noticed that I'm getting my questions down-voted a lot.  I am new to C++ and just now learning and my professor leaves us on our own and its online so I don't have a lab to learn it in so I come here.  Any advice on good books to learn C++ thoroughly?  Any other forums where I can ask questions while I'm learning?

Comment: @ThanksForAskin My (possibly impractical) advice is to learn C first.  C is a much simpler language that is, for the most part, a small subset of C++.  It will get you comfortable with a lot of the syntax, using procedures, pointers, dynamic memory allocation, etc., if you aren't already. Once you have a decent handle on programming in C, then I'd suggest http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html to learn about all the goodies of C++.  PS - Don't worry about a couple of down votes.  Just ask well written questions after you've already tried to tackle them.  Present your work and ask for help.

Comment: @jschultz410 thanks for the feedback.  I was thinking that but I heard that learning C first will make you develop bad habits for coding in C++.  Thoughts?

Comment: @ThanksForAskin It can, if you refuse to adapt the habits you learn in C to C++ appropriately.  Still, C is such a simpler language and it is, for the most part, a subset of C++ that a good understanding of C is very valuable for a C++ programmer.